# Django Textarea contains additional newline

Tags: django, django-forms

Why does a [Django Textarea Widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#textarea) render the additional newline?

```
Textarea().render('name', 'value')
```

Result:

```
'<textarea name="name" cols="40" rows="10">\nvalue</textarea>'
```

Is there a way to avoid the unneeded `\n`?

Comment: It's just the way the template is written: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/textarea.html. Newlines don't really matter in HTML, any reason that you want to avoid them?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the file `textarea.html` where is the `\n` character defined and omit it.

This might help. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates